# How can I apply function to many ML models and save their output?

Tags: r

I have many predictive models.

I have written a function that will predict accuracy.

How can I write another function that will save all the results into one vector?

E.g. *(for illustrative purposes only)*

```
library(randomForest)
url="http://freakonometrics.free.fr/german_credit.csv"
credit=read.csv(url, header = TRUE, sep = ",")
credit$Creditability <- as.factor(credit$Creditability)

#2 models
Random1 <- randomForest(Creditability ~ Credit.Amount +Duration.of.Credit..month., data = credit, mtry = 1)
Random2 <- randomForest(Creditability ~ Credit.Amount +Duration.of.Credit..month., data = credit, mtry = 2)

##Accuracy function 
Accuracy <- function(model){
pred <-predict(model,type ="class",newdata = credit)
tab <-table(credit$Creditability, pred)
Ac <- sum(diag(tab))/(sum(tab))
Ac}

Accuracy(Random1)
Accuracy(Random2)
```

If I have saved the of models used

```
Models <- c(Random1, Random2)
```

How do I then apply accuracy function to this and save the output as a vector?

I try

```
lapply(Models, Accuracy)
```

but get error

```
Error in UseMethod("predict") : no applicable method for 'predict' applied to an object of class "call"
```

Thanks!

Comment: Does `Accuracy(Random1)` work?

Comment: No, no, no. Do Models <- list(...), don't use c there. You want to put the models into a list and not combine the model objects (which are usually lists under the hood). Your use of c is the reason for the error.

Comment: @Mako212 Thanks. Edited it there. Works now.

Roland, thank you. That was the error.